# Student Feedback Survey but Can't Control the Multiple Radio Buttons [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a Student Feedback Survey which will be the ratings is loop but somehow I can't control the radio buttons which will select by the user. It will carried by which the user select in the next question. Here's my code.

[Here's my prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB4mO.png)

[Here's I fetch all the Questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNypk.png)

[The table I fetch the Ratings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umGGJ.png)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zAb8XJ0hwVA

Here's my codes:

```
<?php 
    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM question";
    $r2 = $conn -> query($q2);
?>
<?php 
    while ($row2 = $r2 -> fetch_object()): 
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row2 -> Question_ID ?></td>
            <td>
<?php 
        echo $row2 -> Question_Description 
?>
            </td>
            <td>
<?php
        $q1 = "SELECT * FROM rating ORDER BY Rating_ID ASC";
        $r1 = $conn -> query($q1);
        while($row2 = $r1 -> fetch_object()){
            echo "<input type='radio' name='Rating_ID' value='options'>" . $row2 -> Rating_ID;
        }
?>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php 
    endwhile; 
?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Evaluation</button></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='Rating_ID' value='options'>" . $row2 -> Rating_ID;
```

Having the same name for all radio inputs results in only one radio input of the same name can be selected.

You can make the name of the radio inputs in one row i.e. of a question differs with those in other rows. One possible way is to use the `QUESTION_ID` of each question for the `name` attribute of the radio inputs in that row:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='" . $row2 -> Question_ID . "' value='options'>" . $row -> Rating_ID;
```

Comment: How can I get the values from those radio buttons with their specific questions ?

Comment: @JericoBorja Could you be more specific? If you want to get the values on the client side via Javascript, then look for ways to read DOM input values.  Or if it's on the server side with PHP, then look for how you read form values.

Comment: @ Arga Roh Sahrijal Saragih Is it possible to insert the data the has been selected by the user through $row -> Rating_ID ?